# Prove that a condition for four points in space to be on the same plane can be written as below.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, independence

There are four points in space $P_i(x_i,y_i,z_i)(1\leq i\leq 4)$.

Prove that a condition for these points to be on the same plane can be written as $$\det \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 &1&1 \\
x_1 & x_2&x_3&x_4 \\
y_1 & y_2&y_3&y_4 \\
z_1 & z_2&z_3&z_4
\end{pmatrix} = 0
$$

---

By subtracting the fourth columns from  $j (1\leq i\leq 3)$ columns, the condition turns to be
$$\det \begin{pmatrix}
x_4-x_1 & x_4-x_2&x_4-x_3 \\
y_4-y_1 & y_4-y_2&y_4-y_3 \\
z_4-z_1 & z_4-z_2&z_4-z_3
\end{pmatrix} = 0
$$

The textbook says that this means vectors going to $P_1,P_2,P_3$ from $P_4$ are linearly dependent, thus the vectors lie on the same plane, but I couldn't find out how I can lead that conclusion from that equation.

Comment: When a determinant is zero, the columns (and rows) of the matrix are linearly dependent. What does each column in your second matrix represent?

Comment: @player3236 each represents the vector from $P_j$ to $P_4$

Comment: Then there's your answer.